# ST-HOSVD in Julia

Tags: julia, linear-algebra, tensor

I am trying to implement ST-HOSVD algorithm in Julia because I could not found library which contains ST-HOSVD.

See this paper in Algorithm 1 in page7.
[https://people.cs.kuleuven.be/~nick.vannieuwenhoven/papers/01-STHOSVD.pdf](https://people.cs.kuleuven.be/%7Enick.vannieuwenhoven/papers/01-STHOSVD.pdf)

I cannot reproduce input (4,4,4,4) tensor by approximated tensor whose tucker rank is (2,2,2,2).
I think I have some mistake in indexes of matrix or tensor elements, but I could not locate it.
How to fix it?

If you know library of ST-HOSVD, let me know.
ST-HOSVD is really common way to reduce information. I hope the question helps many Julia user.

```
using TensorToolbox
function STHOSVD(A, reqrank)
    N = ndims(A)

    S = copy(A)
    Sk = undef
    Uk = []
    for k = 1:N
        if k == 1
            Sk = tenmat(S, k)
        end
        Sk_svd = svd(Sk)
        U1 = Sk_svd.U[ :, 1:reqrank[k] ]
        V1t = Sk_svd.V[1:reqrank[k], : ]
        Sigma1 = diagm( Sk_svd.S[1:reqrank[k]] )
        Sk = Sigma1 * V1t
        push!(Uk, U1)
    end

    X = ttm(Sk, Uk[1], 1)
    for k=2:N
        X = ttm(X, Uk[k], k)
    end
    return X
end

A = rand(4,4,4,4)
X = X_STHOSVD(A, [2,2,2,2])
```

**EDIT**

Here, `Sk = tenmat(S, k)` is mode n matricization of tensor S.
S∈R^{I_1×I_2×…×I_N}, S_k∈R^{I_k×(Π_{m≠k}^{N} I_m)}

The function is contained in [TensorToolbox.jl](https://github.com/lanaperisa/TensorToolbox.jl). See "Basis" in Readme.

The definition of mode-k Matricization can be seen [the paper](http://www.kolda.net/publication/TensorReview.pdf) in page 460.

Comment: [TensorDecompositions.jl](https://github.com/yunjhongwu/TensorDecompositions.jl) and [ITensors.jl](https://github.com/ITensor/ITensors.jl) both have tensor SVDs. You should include the implementation (or at at least an explanation) of `tenmat`, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works.
I have seen 26 page in [this slide](https://mycourses.aalto.fi/pluginfile.php/1249889/mod_resource/content/1/Lecture6.pdf)

```
using TensorToolbox
using LinearAlgebra
using Arpack

function STHOSVD(T, reqrank)
    N = ndims(T)
    tensor_shape = size(T)
    for i = 1 : N
        T_i = tenmat(T, i)
        if reqrank[i] == tensor_shape[i]
            USV = svd(T_i)
        else
            USV = svds(T_i; nsv=reqrank[i] )[1]
        end
        T = ttm( T, USV.U * USV.U', i)
    end

    return T
end
```